# Using Active session to prevent Login in every time in the app

Tags: android, facebook, logout

Hi Everybody I implemented application which request user to login with their Facebook Account but each time exit app and want to  open app again it shows logout Button which is not directly and need logout and sign in again to pass to the next activity. Can you please advice me with fixing the code below?

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;


import kavehkamkar.turnup.Test.R;

import org.json.JSONException;



import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Request.GraphUserCallback;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.Session.OpenRequest;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{public static ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uihelper;  
    LoginButton btn;
    String id,firstname,sex ,birthday;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (isOnline()){    
        uihelper =new UiLifecycleHelper(this,callback);  
         uihelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    btn=(LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fbbtn);

                 try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.example.testing", 
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
     else{

          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

          TextView title =  new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            title.setText("Connection Failed");
            title.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            title.setTextSize(17);
            title.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            builder.setCustomTitle(title);



          builder.setMessage("No Internet connection ! Please check that you have a data connection and then try again.")
                 .setCancelable(false)
                 .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                          //do things
                         finish();
                         System.exit(0);}
                 });
          AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
          alert.show();
      }


    }


       private boolean isOnline() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               boolean status=false;
                try{
                    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(0);
                    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        status= true;
                    }else {
                        netInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(1);
                        if(netInfo!=null && netInfo.getState()==NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                            status= true;
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                    return false;
                }
                return status;

            }




    void showMsg(String string)
       {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

private Session.StatusCallback callback =new Session.StatusCallback() 
         {



            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
            {

                if (state.isOpened()){
                    Intent in = new Intent("com.example.Test.Profile");
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
                    bundle.putString("Fb_id",id);
                      session.getAccessToken()  ;
                    bundle.putString("Fb_name", firstname);
                      session.getAccessToken()  ;
                    bundle.putString("Fb_age", birthday);
                     session.getAccessToken()   ;
                        bundle.putString("Fb_sex", sex);
                    in.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(in);

                      btn.post(new Runnable(){

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }});

                }
                onSessionStateChange(session,state,exception);
            }
        };

         void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
         {

            if (state.isOpened()) 
            {

                Log.i("facebook", "Logged in...");

                Request request=Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
                {   

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) 
                    {

                        if(user!=null)
                        {

                            Intent in = new Intent("com.example.Test.Profile");
                            Bundle bundle =new Bundle();  
                             bundle.putString("Fb_id", user.getId());
                           if (user.getBirthday() !=null){

                             String agee = "";
                            String[] age= user.getBirthday().split("/");
                             for(int k = 0; k < age.length; k++){
                                 agee=age[2];
                             }
                             int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);

                             int personage;

                            personage = year -Integer.valueOf( agee);
                             bundle.putString("Fb_age", Integer.toString(personage));
                             birthday=Integer.toString(personage);
                             session.getAccessToken();}

                           bundle.putString("Fb_name", user.getFirstName());
                           if (user.getProperty("gender").toString() !=null){

                              bundle.putString("Fb_sex", user.getProperty("gender").toString());
                              session.getAccessToken();
                              sex=user.getProperty("gender").toString();
                           }
                              in.putExtras(bundle);
                                startActivity(in);
                                 id=user.getId();
                                 session.getAccessToken();
                                 firstname=user.getFirstName();

                        }

                        else
                        {
                            showMsg("its null");
                            showMsg(response.getError().getErrorMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,email,birthday,name,first_name,gender");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

            } 
            else if (state.isClosed()) 
            {
                Log.i("facebook", "Logged out...");
            }
        }    
         public static void logoutFromFB(GraphUserCallback graphUserCallback) {
                Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                if (session != null) {
                    if (!session.isClosed()) {
                        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                        // clear your preferences if saved
                    }
                } else {
                    session = new Session((Context) graphUserCallback);
                    Session.setActiveSession(session);
                    session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                    // clear your preferences if saved
                }}

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {     
        super.onResume();
        if (isOnline()){    uihelper.onResume();    }   

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uihelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (isOnline()){        uihelper.onPause();}
        }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (isOnline()){    uihelper.onDestroy();   }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uihelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
           intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           startActivity(intent);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this question using access token and save this access token in a sharedpreference.

```
package com.example.Test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Calendar;

import kavehkamkar.turnup.Test.R;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  // Your Facebook APP ID
  private static String APP_ID = "Replace with your App "; // 

  // Instance of Facebook Class
  private Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
  private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
  String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
  public static SharedPreferences mPrefs;

  // Buttons
  Button btnFbLogin;


  String access_token;
  long expires;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnFbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fblogin);


    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
     expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);


     if (access_token != null) {
          facebook.authorize(this,
                  new String[] { "email"},
                  new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                      // Function to handle cancel event
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                          btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            getProfileInformation();
                          // Making logout Button visible

                          // Making post to wall visible

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                      // Function to handle error

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                      // Function to handle Facebook errors

                    }

                  });
       }

       if (expires != 0) {
         facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
       }





    /**
     * Login button Click event
     * */
    btnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
        loginToFacebook();
      }
    });

    /**
     * Getting facebook Profile info
     * */


    /**
     * Posting to Facebook Wall
     * */


    /**
     * Showing Access Tokens
     * */


  }

  /**
   * Function to login into facebook
   * */
  public void loginToFacebook() {

    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
     access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
     expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
      facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

      btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

      // Making get profile button visible


      // Making post to wall visible


      // Making show access tokens button visible


      Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
    }

    if (expires != 0) {
      facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
      facebook.authorize(this,
          new String[] { "email"},
          new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
              // Function to handle cancel event
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
              // Function to handle complete event
              // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
              editor.putString("access_token",
                  facebook.getAccessToken());
              editor.putLong("access_expires",
                  facebook.getAccessExpires());
              editor.commit();

              // Making Login button invisible
              btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

              // Making logout Button visible
              getProfileInformation();

              // Making post to wall visible

              // Making show access tokens button visible

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError error) {
              // Function to handle error

            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
              // Function to handle Facebook errors

            }

          });
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }


  /**
   * Get Profile information by making request to Facebook Graph API
   * */
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void getProfileInformation() {
      Bundle params = new Bundle();
      params.putString("fields", "id,email,birthday,name,first_name,gender");

      mAsyncRunner.request("me", params,new RequestListener() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        Log.d("Profile", response);
        String json = response;
        try {
          // Facebook Profile JSON data
          JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);


          final String email = profile.getString("email");

          Intent in = new Intent("com.example.Test.Profile");
          Bundle bundle =new Bundle();  
           bundle.putString("Fb_id", profile.getString("id"));
           if (profile.getString("birthday") !=null){

               String agee = "";
              String[] age= profile.getString("birthday").split("/");
               for(int k = 0; k < age.length; k++){
                 agee=age[2];
               }
               int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);

               int personage;

              personage = year -Integer.valueOf( agee);
               bundle.putString("Fb_age", Integer.toString(personage));            
           }
           bundle.putString("Fb_name",  profile.getString("name"));

           if (profile.getString("gender").toString() !=null){

               bundle.putString("Fb_sex", profile.getString("gender").toString());
           }


             // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name: " + name + "\nEmail: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  in.putExtras(bundle);
                  startActivity(in);



        } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
          Object state) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
          Object state) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
      }
    });


  }

  /**
   * Function to post to facebook wall
   * */
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void postToWall() {
    // post on user's wall.
    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

      @Override
      public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(DialogError e) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancel() {
      }
    });

  }

  /**
   * Function to show Access Tokens
   * */
  public void showAccessTokens() {
    String access_token = facebook.getAccessToken();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Access Token: " + access_token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  /**
   * Function to Logout user from Facebook
   * */
  public void logoutFromFacebook() {
    mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {
      @Override
      public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);
        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(response) == true) {
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
              // make Login button visible
              btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

              // making all remaining buttons invisible


            }

          });

        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
          Object state) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
          Object state) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
      }
    });
  }
  public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
           intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For latest version sdk 4 You can use LoginManager.getInstance().logOut(); for logout from facebook.In your case when your task has been completed or user navigate from that screen you can logout programmatically. Also initialise your sdk FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

If you are using old sdk you have to clear session information using below method

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {

        if (!session.isClosed()) {
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            //clear your preferences if saved
        }
    } else {

        session = new Session(context);
        Session.setActiveSession(session);

        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            //clear your preferences if saved

    }
```

Comment: Well the problem is not log out from account, I did this part programatically. The problem is when I sign in facebook it will integrate information for next activity but when I exit from app and open it again it will show log out button which means that I need to logout  and log in again? I think the problem is regarding access token , But I don't where I should add it and how?

Comment: which facebook sdk version you are using?

Comment: Try using loginButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);

Comment: at the time of loginbutton initialization in onCreate